# Нужно ли выделять звуки звездочками?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, фонетика

Нужно ли выделять звуки звездочками по правилам русского языка?
Пример: *Взрыв* *Тук-тук* *Радостный лай* и так далее.

Answer (score 3):

Нет. Это не относится к правилам русского языка. Подробнее о функциях "звёздочки" на [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#%D0%92_%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5). Чтобы написать про звук, нужно сказать, что он раздался, либо его услышали. В литературе экспериментального характера, которая выходит за рамки традиций русского языка, можно использовать просто назывные предложения, оставляя читателю возможность додумать отсутствующие слова. А в тех случаях, когда речь идёт о простой переписке в чатах, отход от норм и правил допустим, т.к. ваша задача заключается лишь в том, чтобы собеседник вас понял, а не в том, чтобы соответствовать требованиям учебников.

**Дополнение:**
Eagle предположил: "Имелось в виду в субтитрах к фильму или какому-то ролику для людей, которые не слышат". В таких случая возможны любые способы выделения, интуитивно понятные зрителю. Среди них — скобочки, "звёздочки", гарнитура, цвет букв и др. Но это тоже не является областью вопросов, решаемых правилами русского языка. Примеры таких, "функциональных" ремарок часто можно увидеть в пьесах, например. И часто там хватает скобочек, либо написания с новой строки. В субтитрах это тоже может оказаться достаточным, так как реплики требуют постановки длинного тире перед фразой. Дополнительное оформление потребуется при большой густоте текста на экране.

Comment: Я думаю имелось в виду в субтитрах к фильму или какому-то ролику для людей, которые не слышат. Если человек не слышит, он может не понимать, что происходит по сюжету, что раздался, например, взрыв, какой-то горох, слышны звуки песни и т. п. Поэтому названия таких звуков могут выделяться, чтоб понятно было, что это именно звук взрыва, а не кто-то сказал, слово «взрыв».

Comment: @Eagle ну да. Дополнил ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: «гарнитура шрифта». Гарнитура — это более общее понятие, чем шрифт. «Гарнитура шрифта» — это как сказать «фрукты яблока». Википедия: «Гарнитура в типографике — набор из одного или нескольких шрифтов в одном или нескольких размерах и начертаниях, имеющих стилевое единство рисунка и состоящих из определённого набора типографских знаков». Не знаю происхождение слова, но думаю из ненемецкого Garnitur «украшение, убор» от французского garniture (словарь Фасмера). Похоже на гарнитур — набор мебели одинакового дизайна (полный комплект для одной цели). И гарнитура — набор шрифтов одинакового дизайна.